# C++ template class: No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, shared

I'm trying to build a template class that holds a pointer to a vector, which itself holds pointers.

```
template <typename S, typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<aNode<S,T>> head{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<aNode<S,T>>> positionList; // <<- This guy

    void add(S const & k, T const & v)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<aNode<S,T>> newNode = std::make_shared<aNode<S,T>>();
        newNode->set_data(k, v);
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            auto current = head;
            while (current->next != nullptr) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
        positionList->push_back(newNode); // <<- Error here
    } 
    [...]
```

On line 20, the compiler throws error `No matching member function for call to 'push_back'`.

Now the -> operator should give me access to the vector, and vector certainly has a push_back method. The only thing I can think of is that the vector was no initialized. 
Changing line 4 to `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<aNode<S,T>>()> positionList;` throws error

```
Member reference base type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<aNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<aNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > ()>::element_type' (aka 'std::__1::vector<aNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<aNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > ()') is not a structure or union
```

(still on line 20).

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: `positionlist` is a shared pointer to a vector of nodes, but you try to push back a shared pointer to a node, that doesnt fit

Comment: `newNode` has type `std::shared_ptr<aNode<S,T>>`, but your vector stores `aNode<S,T>`.

Comment: And `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<aNode<S,T>>()>` is wrong. To initialize empty vector inside `shared_ptr` use simply `std::make_shared()` in constructor.

Comment: Do you really want pointer on vector, do you share it? `std::vector` is generally sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, `positionList` should be:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<aNode<S, T>>>> positionList;
```

Comment: Duh! I couldn't see the woods for the trees there - thanks a lot Jarod42!